# Toggling from Picker to Image view causes an index out of range error in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a view that uses a button to toggle between a Picker and an Image that is a result of the Picker selection. When quickly toggling from the image to the Picker and immediately back, I get a crash with the following error:

`Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:600: Fatal error: Index out of range`

Toggling less quickly doesn't cause this, nor does toggling in the other direction (picker to image and back). Here is the offending code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingPicker = false
    @State private var currentNum = 0
    @State private var numbers: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack(spacing: 15) {
                Spacer()
                if showingPicker {
                    Picker("Number", selection: $currentNum) {
                        ForEach(0..<numbers.count, id: \.self) {
                            Text("\($0)")
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "\(currentNum).circle")
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button("Toggle") {
                    showingPicker = !showingPicker
                }
                
            }
    }
}
```

The code works otherwise. I'm new to SwiftUI so I'm still wrapping my head around how views are created/destroyed. I tried changing the order of the properties thinking maybe the array was being accessed before it was recreated(if that's even something that happens) but that had no effect. I also tried `ForEach(numbers.indices)` instead of `ForEach(0..<numbers.count)`, but it has the same result.

**Edit

I figured out a stop-gap for now. I added `@State private var buttonEnabled = true` and modified the button:

```swift
Button("Toggle") {
    showingPicker = !showingPicker
    buttonEnabled = false
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.35) {
        buttonEnabled = true
    }
}
.disabled(buttonEnabled == false)
```

To debounce it. I still want to figure out the problem and make a real fix.

**Edit

Based on comments I've modified the code to take array indexing out of the equation and to better reflect the actual project I'm working on. The code still works, but a quick toggle will cause the exact same crash and error. It also seems to only happen when the .wheel style picker is used, other picker styles don't have this behavior.

```swift
enum Icons: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case ear = "Ear"
    case cube = "Cube"
    case eye = "Eye"
    case forward = "Forward"
    case gear = "Gear"
    
    func image() -> Image {
        switch self {
        case .ear:
            return Image(systemName: "ear")
        case .cube:
            return Image(systemName: "cube")
        case .eye:
            return Image(systemName: "eye")
        case .forward:
            return Image(systemName: "forward")
        case .gear:
            return Image(systemName: "gear")
        }
    }
    
    var id: Self {
        return self
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingPicker = false
    @State private var currentIcon = Icons.allCases[0]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
            Spacer()
            if showingPicker {
                Picker("Icon", selection: $currentIcon) {
                    ForEach(Icons.allCases) {
                        $0.image()
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
            } else {
                currentIcon.image()
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Toggle") {
                showingPicker.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

** Edited once more to remove .self, still no change

Comment: Ranges and the use of self is considered unsafe with SwiftUI for this exact reason, you can watch Demystify SwiftUI for more.

Comment: For toggling use ```showingPicker.toggle()``` instead. Makes it much easier.

Answer (score 1):

ForEach is not a for loop, you can't use `array.count` and `id:\.self` you need to use a real id param or use the `Identifiable` protocol.

However if you just need numbers it also supports this:

`ForEach(0..<5) { i in`

As long as you don't try to look up an array using `i`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've added a revised version of my code that I believe reflects your suggestions. Unfortunately a rapid toggle causes the exact same crash and error.

Comment: I made an additional modification to avoid referring to \.self in the ForEach block, still no change with the faulty behavior. Also, only wheel pickers have this error, all other styles work fine. I'm starting to think this is a SwiftUI bug, but again I'm new to SwiftUI so I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug when using Picker with ForEach. The exact crash point is  -[UIPickerView tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:], which is the underlying implementation of Picker view.

If you list the picker items manually, it would work properly.

```
Picker("Icon", selection: $currentIcon) {
    Icons.ear.image().tag(Icons.ear)
    Icons.cube.image().tag(Icons.cube)
    Icons.eye.image().tag(Icons.eye)
    Icons.forward.image().tag(Icons.forward)
    Icons.gear.image().tag(Icons.gear)
}
.pickerStyle(.wheel)
```